The system cannot deploy: How can I fix that error coming from cPanel?
I have been trying to simplify my workflow by having my website automatically deployed whenever I push on my Git remote repository. However, when I try to setup the automatic deployment, I get this error:

The system cannot deploy
For deployment, ensure that your repository meets the following requirements:

A valid .cpanel.yml file exists. For more information, read our documentation.
No uncommitted changes exist on the checked-out branch.

I have tried so many configurations for my .cpanel.yml nothing will work. I also have a clean working tree: no uncommitted changes, everything is merged, nothing is pending.
Here is the structure of my project:
REPO/
├── index.html
└── assets/
    ├── images/
    ├── scripts/
    └── styles/

Here is what I have tried so far:

---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/username/public_html/
    - /bin/mkdir -p $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp index.html $DEPLOYPATH
    - /bin/cp -R assets $DEPLOYPATH

My other attemps aren't relevant they were just tiny changes like trying double quotes or deploying by using *. Nothing works!
